# Font rendering error when converting pdf to jpg with imagemagick

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript, ubuntu-18.04

I have a pdf that I am trying to convert into a jpg image with imagemagick on a digital ocean server with Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

When I do it on my home computer (Ubuntu 16.04 OS, desktop version) the conversion runs successfully.

When I run the same command on the server machine, the generated image have a problem in the rendering of the text. In particular on some lines in place of text I see rectangulars, as you can see in the image:

[image: Error in displaying fonts].

I suppose it has to do with some fonts. So I executed pdffonts on the original pdf, which displays:

```
name                                 type              encoding        emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- --------- 
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no       8  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no       9  0 
e42697+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi         yes no  yes     10  0
```

So now I think that the problem arises because the Helvetica fonts are not embedded in the pdf.

The command I used to convert is the following:

```
convert invoice.pdf[0] -encoding WinAnsi -thumbnail 800x -background white -alpha remove -quality 95 -gravity center -format jpg jpg:out.jpg
```

So the question is: is there a way to add some options to the convert command to avoid the issue, or is it some package I can install on my server? I have already tried the -font options, without success.

Here are the versions of the tools I am using:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

$ ghostscript --version
9.22
```

Thank you for your help.
In case you need more info please let me know.

**EDIT**
I tried also to compile from source the newest imagemagick 7, but still the same happens.

```
$ convert -list  configure

Path: /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.8//config-Q16HDRI/configure.xml

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC             gcc
CFLAGS         -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -                
I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 - 
I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -                
I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 - 
I/usr/include/OpenEXR  -I/usr/include/lqr-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 - 
I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -I/usr/include/freetype2 - 
I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 - 
I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -pthread    -fopenmp -g -O2 
-Wall -mtune=core2 -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 - 
DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CODER_PATH     /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.8/modules-Q16HDRI/coders
CONFIGURE      ./configure  '--with-gslib=yes'
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/
COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS       -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
CXX            g++
CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      bzlib djvu mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pango png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS  --disable-deprecated  --with-quantum-depth=16  --with-jemalloc=no  --with-umem=no  --with-autotrace=no  --with-fontpath=  --with-rsvg=no  --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7
EXEC-PREFIX    /usr/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/bin
FEATURES       DPC HDRI Cipher OpenMP
FILTER_PATH    /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.8/modules-Q16HDRI/filters
GIT_REVISION   14730
HOST           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
INCLUDE_PATH   /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
LDFLAGS        -L/usr/local/lib
LIB_VERSION    0x708
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 7,0,8,11
LIBRARY_PATH   /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.8
LIBS            -ljbig -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype  -ljpeg -lgs -llqr-1 - 
lglib-2.0 -lpng16 -lz  -ldjvulibre -lfftw3   -lfontconfig -lfreetype    - 
lwmflite  -lXext -lXt   -lSM -lICE -lX11  -llzma -lbz2 -lIlmImf -lImath - 
lHalf -lIex -lIexMath -lIlmThread -lpthread  -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 - 
lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcairo   -lxml2  -lz    -lm -lgomp
NAME           ImageMagick
PCFLAGS        -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 - 
DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PREFIX         /usr/local
QuantumDepth   16
RELEASE_DATE   2018-09-22
SHARE_PATH     /usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7
SHAREARCH_PATH /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.8/config-Q16HDRI
TARGET_CPU     x86_64
TARGET_OS      linux-gnu
TARGET_VENDOR  pc
VERSION        7.0.8
WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FEATURES       OpenMP
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16
```

**EDIT 2**

I was able to restrict the problem to ghostscript.
Now I have the same issue also when executing following command:

```
$ gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 - 
sOutputFile=gs_out_300.png invoice.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.22 (2017-10-04)
Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from 
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 4509328 2901747 2393680 1046799 3 done.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4575440 3079563 
2413880 1062624 3 done.
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same versions of Imagemagick. IM 6.9.7.4 is very old. But on Linux, they do not upgrade the version number when they patch. So the date associated with the version is more important. In your case 20170114 is 1/14/2017, so well over a year old. Might you have different dates on your two systems. Also I do not see either gs or gslib listed in your delegates. On my Mac, I get gslib showing that tells me Ghostscript is installed. Also try `convert -list configure` and check the delegates. Also GS 9.22, had some trouble. It is now at 9.25. Check your versions of freetype

Comment: fmw42 you should make that an answer :-) I'd bet its an old version of FreeType. Also, as I was going to put in an answer, the OP should upgrade to 9.25 **anyway** as it has important security fixes.